# Save multiple checkbox with different name? (Laravel)

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5

I have problem when saved multiple checkbox with different name.

I have case create permission for menu and menu have different access like create, read, update, delete, etc

I try with this code but I get not valid result

Here is my blade template

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="bs4-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Menu</th>
                <th>Create</th>
                <th>Read</th>
                <th>Update</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
                <th>Approve</th>
                <th>Export PDF</th>
                <th>Export Excel</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($permission_menus as $permission_menu)
                   <tr>
                       <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                       <td>
                           {{ $permission_menu->name }} <input type="checkbox" name="menus_id[]" value="{{ $permission_menu->id }}">
                       </td>
                       <td>
                           <input type="checkbox" name="create_access[]" value="0" onclick="changeFlag(this)">
                       </td>
                       <td>
                           <input type="checkbox" name="read_access[]" value="0" onclick="changeFlag(this)">
                       </td>
                       <td>
                           <input type="checkbox" name="update_access[]" value="0" onclick="changeFlag(this)">
                       </td>
                       <td>
                           <input type="checkbox" name="delete_access[]" value="0" onclick="changeFlag(this)">
                       </td>
                       <td>
                           <input type="checkbox" name="approve_access[]" value="0" onclick="changeFlag(this)">
                       </td>
                       <td>
                           <input type="checkbox" name="export_pdf_access[]" value="0" onclick="changeFlag(this)">
                       </td>
                       <td>
                           <input type="checkbox" name="export_excel_access[]" value="0" onclick="changeFlag(this)">
                       </td>
                   </tr>
               @endforeach
           </tbody>
       </table>
   </div>
```

And here my store method

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'user_access' => 'required',
        ], [
            'user_access.required' => 'User harus dipilih!',
        ]);

        $index = 0;

        foreach($request->menus_id as $menu_id)
        {
            $create_access = $request->create_access;
            $read_access = $request->read_access;
            $update_access = $request->update_access;
            $delete_access = $request->delete_access;
            $approve_access = $request->approve_access;
            $export_pdf_access = $request->export_pdf_access;
            $export_excel_access = $request->export_excel_access;


            if (!isset($create_access[$index])) {
                $create_access[$index] = 0;
            }

            if(!isset($read_access[$index])){
                $read_access[$index] = 0;
            }

            if(!isset($update_access[$index])){
                $update_access[$index] = 0;
            }

            if(!isset($delete_access[$index])){
                $delete_access[$index] = 0;
            }

            if(!isset($approve_access[$index])){
                $approve_access[$index] = 0;
            }

            if(!isset($export_pdf_access[$index])){
                $export_pdf_access[$index] = 0;
            }

            if(!isset($export_excel_access[$index])){
                $export_excel_access[$index] = 0;
            }



            $permission = [
                'menu_id' => $menu_id,
                'create_access' => $create_access[$index],
                'read_access' => $read_access[$index],
                'update_access' => $update_access[$index],
                'delete_access' => $delete_access[$index],
                'approve_access' => $approve_access[$index],
                'export_pdf_access' => $export_pdf_access[$index],
                'export_excel_access' => $export_excel_access[$index],
                'user_id' => $request->user_id,
                'user_access' => $request->user_access
            ];


            DB::table('permissions')->insert($permission);

            $index++;
        }

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Hak akses berhasil di set!');
    }
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: can you you post dd($request->all());

Comment: Here result for dd($request->all());

https://yapics.com/a4310lDt705-5666

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you uncheck one of the menu items without unchecking all the permissions under that menu then you will get inconsistent results. You can always force the identifier as the menu index:

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="bs4-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Menu</th>
            <th>Create</th>


            <th>Read</th>
            <th>Update</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
            <th>Approve</th>
            <th>Export PDF</th>
            <th>Export Excel</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach ($permission_menus as $permission_menu)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
            <td>
                {{ $permission_menu->name }} <input type="checkbox" name="menus_id[]"
                                                    value="{{ $permission_menu->id }}">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="create_access[{{$permission_menu->id}}]" value="0" onclick="changeFlag(this)">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="read_access[{{$permission_menu->id}}]" value="0" onclick="changeFlag(this)">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="update_access[{{$permission_menu->id}}]" value="0" onclick="changeFlag(this)">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete_access[{{$permission_menu->id}}]" value="0" onclick="changeFlag(this)">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="approve_access[{{$permission_menu->id}}]" value="0" onclick="changeFlag(this)">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="export_pdf_access[{{$permission_menu->id}}]" value="0"
                       onclick="changeFlag(this)">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="export_excel_access[{{$permission_menu->id}}]" value="0"
                       onclick="changeFlag(this)">
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </thead>
</table>
```

This way you can match the results correctly:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
        $this->validate($request, [
            'user_access' => 'required',
        ], [
            'user_access.required' => 'User harus dipilih!',
        ]);

        foreach($request->menus_id as $menu_id)
        {
            $create_access = $request->create_access;
            $read_access = $request->read_access;
            $update_access = $request->update_access;
            $delete_access = $request->delete_access;
            $approve_access = $request->approve_access;
            $export_pdf_access = $request->export_pdf_access;
            $export_excel_access = $request->export_excel_access;


            if (!isset($create_access[$menu_id])) {
                $create_access[$menu_id] = 0;
            }

            if(!isset($read_access[$menu_id])){
                $read_access[$menu_id] = 0;
            }

            if(!isset($update_access[$menu_id])){
                $update_access[$menu_id] = 0;
            }

            if(!isset($delete_access[$menu_id])){
                $delete_access[$menu_id] = 0;
            }

            if(!isset($approve_access[$index])){
                $approve_access[$index] = 0;
            }

            if(!isset($export_pdf_access[$menu_id])){
                $export_pdf_access[$menu_id] = 0;
            }

            if(!isset($export_excel_access[$menu_id])){
                $export_excel_access[$menu_id] = 0;
            }



            $permission = [
                'menu_id' => $menu_id,

                'create_access' => $create_access[$menu_id],       
               'read_access' => $read_access[$menu_id],
                'update_access' => $update_access[$menu_id],
                'delete_access' => $delete_access[$menu_id],
                'approve_access' => $approve_access[$menu_id],
                'export_pdf_access' => $export_pdf_access[$menu_id],
                'export_excel_access' => $export_excel_access[$menu_id],
                'user_id' => $request->user_id,
                'user_access' => $request->user_access
            ];


            DB::table('permissions')->insert($permission);
        }

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Hak akses berhasil di set!');
    }
```

Note: Instead of doing `if(!isset($x[$menu_id])) { $x[$menu_id] = 0; }` you can just do `$x[$menu_id]??0` in the `$permission` array